# Error while serializing List<Object>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Object>` which I am trying to serialize using the `XmlSerializer` and save to the disk but this piece of code generates an error while trying to serialize the file.

According to the thrown error message I get, I don't see anything wrong here and I think I need an extra pair of eyes on this.

Does anyone have a good idea as to why this keeps me awake all night? :/

I know the list contains the element so there is something going wrong with the types perhaps? Tried `Type[]` but it gives the same problem.

```
public static void createFileXml(String path)
{           
    //This creates an error while serializing
    XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Object>));
    TextWriter txtwrt = new StreamWriter(path);
    try
    {
        xmlser.Serialize(txtwrt, lstCopy);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (txtwrt != null)
        {
            txtwrt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: what's your list `type` ?

Comment: How can `txtwrt` ever be null?

Comment: Error msg: "There was an error generating the XML document.". lstCopy is a copy of the List<Object> lst;. Type = Object. txtwrt can be null if the listItem is equal to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a generic serializeobject method that I wrote a while back. May be it will help you too.

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
{
    try
    {
        string xmlString = null;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, enc))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            }
            xmlString = enc.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            return xmlString;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Note: You may need to alter it as per your needs.

Comment: I would remove try catch all swallow. It's bad practice.

Comment: This helps alot and you are using wich is much better practice! Thanks alot Azhar!

Comment: @user1501127 No probs. Glad that it helped out :)